# node-gyb build error on hello world

Tags: node.js, node-gyp

I was trying to compile the [node hello world addon](https://github.com/joyent/node/tree/master/test/addons/hello-world) and when I call 
`node-gyp configure build` it generates several errors.

```
../binding.cc:6:19: error: unknown type name 'FunctionCallbackInfo'
    void Method(const FunctionCallbackInfo<Value>& args) {
                      ^
../binding.cc:6:39: error: expected ')'
    void Method(const FunctionCallbackInfo<Value>& args) {
                                          ^
../binding.cc:6:12: note: to match this '('
    void Method(const FunctionCallbackInfo<Value>& args) {
               ^
../binding.cc:8:15: error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'v8::HandleScope'
      HandleScope scope(isolate);
                  ^     ~~~~~~~
/***/***/.node-gyp/0.10.36/deps/v8/include/v8.h:473:3: note: candidate constructor not viable: no known conversion from 'v8::Isolate *' to 'const v8::HandleScope' for 1st
          argument
      HandleScope(const HandleScope&);
      ^
/****/***/.node-gyp/0.10.36/deps/v8/include/v8.h:448:3: note: candidate constructor not viable: requires 0 arguments, but 1 was provided
      HandleScope();
      ^
../binding.cc:9:3: error: use of undeclared identifier 'args'
      args.GetReturnValue().Set(String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, "world"));
      ^
../binding.cc:9:37: error: no member named 'NewFromUtf8' in 'v8::String'
      args.GetReturnValue().Set(String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, "world"));
```

What can be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the example assumes you're running Node 0.12, but you're running Node 0.10 (0.10.36 by the looks of it). There have been big (backward-incompatible) changes in the way addons are structured in Node 0.12.

Here's the 0.10-compatible version: https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/aa35564ca1c9f3854bc5f7983f2f00cb51f67ffe/test/addons/hello-world/binding.cc

An awesome package that will take care of a lot of the differences between Node versions is [`nan`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nan).

Comment: Thats the problem. Thanks.

Comment: is it compatible with node 4.2.2?

Comment: @Carlos.V no, but [try this](https://nodejs.org/api/addons.html#addons_hello_world).

Comment: I'm working with Meteor 1.3.5 (who run a node 0.10.46) and I have the same problem with a package `s2geometry-node` on dependency. 
Do I have a solution or I have to recreate an-other package with different dependency ?

Comment: @Arthur I don't have experience with Meteor, but can't you upgrade the Node version it uses? If not, then you can try and find the last version of `s2geometry-node` that still works on Node 0.10.

Comment: @robertklep No you can't update NodeJS on Meteor, but I found node-s2 who work with Node 0.10. And Meteor 1.4 with Node 4 is released today, so it's work fine now